# Oracle Hierarchy with shared members (double parent members)

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I'm working with hierarchical data in which there are some keys that has double or triple parents.

I have to write a hierarchical query to represent the hierarchy, but this double or triple parent keys must appear alone in the tree, displaying their childs is only allowed in the first key found in the three.

```
 WITH HER(CHILD, PARENT) AS (
     SELECT 'A' AS CHILD, null  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'B' AS CHILD, 'A'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'C' AS CHILD, 'A'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'D' AS CHILD, 'C'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'E' AS CHILD, 'D'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'F' AS CHILD, null  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'G' AS CHILD, 'F'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'C' AS CHILD, 'G'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION  --<<--- shared
     SELECT 'H' AS CHILD,  null AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'B' AS CHILD,  'H'  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION  --<<--- shared
     SELECT 'X' AS CHILD,  null AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'Y' AS CHILD,  'X'  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'Z' AS CHILD,  'Y'  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'C' AS CHILD,  'Z'  AS PARENT FROM DUAL       --<<--- shared  
    )
     SELECT 
         LPAD(' ', 7*(LEVEL-1),' ')||CHILD||' - '||PARENT
     FROM HER
     START WITH PARENT IS NULL
     CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD = PARENT
```

;

The result from this query is this, but it's not exactly what I'm trying to get:

```
----------
A - 
       B - A
       C - A
              D - C
                     E - D
F - 
       G - F
              C - G
                     *D - C*
                            *E - D*
H - 
       B - H
X - 
       Y - X
              Z - Y
                     C - Z
                            *D - C*
                                   *E - D*
```

Rows D-C and E-D should just be displayin in the first appearance of "C" key. So those I marked with "*" should not appear.

I know that I could just create a secondary query in which I spot this double-parent keys and then exclude rows based on this.
But I wonder if there's a shortest way to do it, working with the hiearchy itself.... if there's a way to know that a key already has another parent.
(Since this goes in a view, I need to do this in a query, not PL/SQL.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "first" occurrence? Rows in a result set are not ordered (they are like balls in a basket), so the question doesn't make much sense. All the rows in the result set are generated simultaneously (perhaps even physically by vectorized processing, and in any case logically). So even after you clarify what you mean by "first", it is unlikely you can do this in one pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit I am generally sql-server so this is a thought for you but it may need some tweaking and syntax help.  But what about adding a ROW_NUMBER() partitioned at Child level and adding a second condition in your connect by clause to limit the recursion.  Perhaps something like this?

```
 WITH HER(CHILD, PARENT) AS (
     SELECT 'A' AS CHILD, null  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'B' AS CHILD, 'A'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'C' AS CHILD, 'A'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'D' AS CHILD, 'C'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'E' AS CHILD, 'D'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'F' AS CHILD, null  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'G' AS CHILD, 'F'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'C' AS CHILD, 'G'   AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION  --<<--- shared
     SELECT 'H' AS CHILD,  null AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'B' AS CHILD,  'H'  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION  --<<--- shared
     SELECT 'X' AS CHILD,  null AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'Y' AS CHILD,  'X'  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'Z' AS CHILD,  'Y'  AS PARENT FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'C' AS CHILD,  'Z'  AS PARENT FROM DUAL       --<<--- shared  
    )

    , HERChildRowNum(CHILD, PARENT, ChildRowNum) AS (

       SELECT
          CHILD,
          PARENT,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CHILD ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as ChildRowNum
       FROM
          HER
    )


     SELECT 
         LPAD(' ', 7*(LEVEL-1),' ')||CHILD||' - '||PARENT
     FROM HERChildRowNum
     START WITH PARENT IS NULL
     CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD = PARENT AND (PRIOR ChildRowNum = ChildRowNum OR ChildRowNum>1)
```

Comment: Impressive!, thanks.... quite close.... but this solution will also desappear rows C-G and C-Z, and those should appear in the report. Just their children should be off.... :(

Comment: @CraigStevensson - this is (almost) the correct solution in Oracle, but I thought your requirement was specifically to avoid a "secondary query". This solution (and probably any other possible solution) does use a secondary query. Hoping you are OK with that (apparently you are).

Comment: @CraigStevensson - to fix this solution for Oracle, in the definition of ROW_NUMBER() change ORDER BY (SELECT 0) to simply ORDER BY 0 (or ORDER BY NULL), and in PARTITION BY CHILD add PARENT like so: PARTITION BY CHILD, PARENT. This will keep one RANDOM copy of each child-parent; if you want a specific one, you must determine what ordering should be (use it in ORDER BY).

Comment: @Matt Changing the connect by to this:

CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD = PARENT 
     AND (PRIOR ChildRowNum = ChildRowNum OR ChildRowNum>1)

will do the trick !! :) Thank you!

Comment: @mathguy Adding "parent" to the partition will break the logic. Matt solution was to partition by child, so, the 2nd child and further are identified and handled.

Comment: @CraigStevensson I see it now, you are right - I didn't follow Matt's logic closely.

Comment: I thought it might need some tweaking, I don't have an oracle instance so I cannot test the connect by method, please feel free to edit the answer with the syntax that worked for you in the end.  Cheers!